# GitLab CI/CD - deploy images

Tags: docker, gitlab

I have problem with GitLab CI/CD. I try build image and run to server where i have runner. My gitlab-ci.yaml

```
image: docker:latest

services:
  - docker:dind

variables:
  TEST_NAME: registry.gitlab.com/pawelcyrklaf/learn-devops:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

before_script:
  - docker login -u pawelcyrklaf -p examplepass registry.gitlab.com

build_image:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build -t $TEST_NAME .
    - docker push $TEST_NAME

deploy_image:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - docker pull $TEST_NAME
    - docker kill $(docker ps -q) || true
    - docker rm $(docker ps -a -q) || true
    - docker run -dt -p 8080:80 --name gitlab_learn $TEST_NAME
```

My Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:centos7
RUN yum install httpd -y
COPY index.html /var/www/html/

CMD [“/usr/sbin/httpd”,” -D”,” FOREGROUND”]
EXPOSE 80
```

Docker images is build successfully it is in registry, also deploy is successful, but when i execute docker ps, i don't have running this image.
[image]
I do all this same with this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eeXfb05ysg4

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Job is scheduled in container together with another service container which has docker inside. It works, it starts container but after job finish, neighbour service with docker stops too. You are checking, and see no container on the host.
Try to remove:

```
services:
  - docker:dind
```

Also, check out [predefined list of CI variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#list-all-environment-variables). You can omit using hardcoded credentials and image path.

P.S. you use to kill and rm all containers and your CI will someday remove containers which are not managed buy this repo...

Comment: Removing Docker-in-Docker service will make the build fail as `docker:latest` image by default connects to Docker daemon using URL `tcp://docker:2375` and without the service there will be nothing there listening.

Answer (score 0):

> when i execute docker ps, i don't have running this image

You didn't mention how you check running container so I assume next considerations

1. Make sure you physically check at the right runner.
   As soon you didn't set any [`tags`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#tags) on jobs it will pick first available. You can see at which runner it executed at the job page
2. Make sure your container is not down or finished.
   To see all containers use `docker ps -a` — it shows all container even stopped one. There would be exit code by which you could determine the reason. Debug it with `docker logs {container_id}` (put container_id without braces)

Answer (score 0):

**Gitlab.com:**

Not sure you can run a docker application in your Gitlab CI, try removing the `-d` option in your `docker run` command which will run the docker in the background.

```sh
$ docker run -t -p 8080:80 --name gitlab_learn $TEST_NAME
```

If this does work, it will probably force the pipeline to never finish and it will drain your CI/CD minutes.

**Self-hosted Gitlab:**

Your Gitlab CI is meant to run actions to build and deploy your application, so it doesn't make sense to have your application running on the same instance your Gitlab CI runner does. Even if you want to run the app on the same instance, it shouldn't be running on the same container the runner does and **to achieve this you should configure Gitlab CI runner to use the docker on the host**.

**Anyways, would strongly recommend deploying somewhere outside where your Gitlab runner is running and even better to a managed docker service, Kubernetes or AWS ECS.**

Comment: Lastly i will deploy container to k8s :)

Comment: Then take a look at https://docs.docker.com/get-started/kube-deploy/ :)

Comment: @PawelC updated my answer, try removing `-d` option from your `docker run` command

Answer (score -1):

You did not specify what your setup is, but based on information in your question I can deduce that you're using gitlab.com (as opposed to private GitLab instance) and self-hosted runner with Docker executor.

**You cannot use a runner with Docker executor to deploy containers directly to the underlying Docker installation.**

There are two ways to do this:

1. Use a runner with a [shell executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/shell.html) as described in the YT tutorial you posted.
2. Prepare a helper image that will use SSH to connect to your server and run docker commands there.